# hide checkbox after clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a checkbox and once it's checked, some a div element will appear. I would like to hide the checkbox after it's clicked so only the div element shows up.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>
<label>Check the box to agree to our terms. After agreeing, you will be able to view our products and checkout.<input name="colorCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="red" /></label>
</div>
<div class="red box">content shows up here</div>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                $(".red").toggle();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the checkbox by referring to `this`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][value="red"]').click(function () {
        $(".red").show();
        $(this).hide()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rxr4nyz8/)

Also note that the change handler is added only to the checkbox with value red instead of targeting all the checkboxes

Comment: why not click instead? some browsers would need a blur to trigger change

Comment: @mplungjan There is nothing wrong with click - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rxr4nyz8/3/

Comment: Thanks. Is there also a way to hide the label as well?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a version that can survive a reload

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name="colorCheckbox"]').on("click",function () {
    $("."+this.value).toggle(this.checked);
    $(this).toggle(!this.checked);
  }).triggerHandler("click"); // initialise
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label>Check the box to agree to our terms. After agreeing, you will be able to view our products and checkout.<input name="colorCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="red" /></label>
</div>
<div class="red box">content shows up here</div>
```